# How can I add a Chromecast of the entire WebView object?

Tags: flutter, dart, chromecast

I'm writing to you because I have an issue and I can't find any information online. Basically, I have a Flutter app that is essentially a WebView of a website, and I need to add a Chromecast button to the appBar in such a way that Chromecast can cast the entire WebView to the TV and allow control of that specific web page. Is it possible?

i tried dart_chromecast 0.3.3 and i found this example:

```
AppBar(
  title: const Text("ChromeCast APP"),
  actions: <Widget>[
    if (_isCasting)
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.cast_connected),
        onPressed: () {
          Chromecast.instance.disconnect();
        },
      )
    else
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.cast),
        onPressed: () async {
          final selectedDevice = await Chromecast.instance.showDialog(context);
          if (selectedDevice != null) {
            Chromecast.instance.connectToDevice(selectedDevice);
          }
        },
      ),
  ],
)
```

but it doesn't do what I expect and above all it's an example that has little to do with what I need :/